# How to update other rows by getting number from the previous updated rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, rows

I have the following table, named "leave" :

```
ID  |  Employee  |  Numb1  |  Numb2  | Numb3  
1   |      4     |    12   |    2    |  10
2   |      4     |    10   |    3    |   7
3   |      4     |     7   |    2    |   5
```

The process is when I update the first row the Numb1 and Numb3 in another row will also updated by the value of Numb3 of the first row.

The output I was hoping for Is like i this table :
the case is when I change the Numb **2** to **3** of the first row

```
ID  |  Employee  |  Numb1  |  Numb2  | Numb3  
1   |      4     |    12   |    3    |   9
2   |      4     |     9   |    3    |   6
3   |      4     |     6   |    2    |   4
```

Here is my code :

```
//Form Input
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
//Form Input END

$query_leave          = mysql_query("SELECT 
    Numb1, 
    Numb2, 
    Numb3 
    FROM leave 
    WHERE 
    ID = '$id_edit'");
$data                 = mysql_fetch_array($query_leave);

$remains              = $data[0] - $amount; 

$query_update         = mysql_query("UPDATE leave SET
    ID                = '$idkaryawan',
    Numb2             = '$amount',
    Numb3             = '$remains',
    WHERE ID          = '$id_edit'");

$query_leave2         = mysql_query("SELECT 
    Numb1, 
    Numb2, 
    Numb3 
    FROM leave 
    WHERE 
    ID       <> '$id_edit' AND
    Employee =  4");
$data2                = mysql_fetch_array($query_leave2);

$remains2             = $data2[0] - $data2[1];

$query_update2        = mysql_query("UPDATE leave SET
    Numb1             = '$remains'
    WHERE 
    ID       <> '$id_edit' AND
    Employee =  4");
```

The output when I use the above code is :

```
ID  |  Employee  |  Numb1  |  Numb2  | Numb3  
1   |      4     |    12   |    3    |   9
2   |      4     |     9   |    3    |   6
3   |      4     |     9   |    2    |   6
```

My Problem is I don't know how to loop it

Currently, I'm using PHP native to develop this program
Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Add the php code you wrote and explain the problem you have

Comment: the problem is I don't know how to loop it

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how loop works in PHP? and in general?

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner..I have updated my questions, I also add the code and the output I have

Comment: Don't use the _deprecated and insecure_ `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.